# Pause, add_job, remove_job in apscheduler with Gunicorn

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gunicorn, apscheduler

In the following snippet , I tried to `remove_job` , `add_job` , `start` from paused and `pause` the `BackgroundScheduler` provided by `apscheduler.schedulers`.

```
from flask import Flask
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
      
def this_job():
    print("the job")
  

app = Flask(__name__)
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(
    daemon=True,
    jobstores={"default": SQLAlchemyJobStore(url="sqlite:///jobs.sqlite")},
)
scheduler.start()


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Congratulations, it's a web app!"


@app.route("/remove_schedule")
def remove_job():
    scheduler.remove_job(job_id="this_job")
    return "job removed"


@app.route("/pause_scheduler")
def pause_scheduler():
    scheduler.pause()
    return "paused scheduler"


@app.route("/resume_scheduler")
def resume_scheduler():
    scheduler.start(paused=True)
    return "resume scheduler"


@app.route("/schedule")
def start_job():
    scheduler.add_job(
        "this_job",
        "cron",
        id=this_job,
        year="*",
        month="*",
        day="*",
        minute="*",
        max_instances=2,
        replace_existing=True,
        misfire_grace_time=240,
    )
    return "job started"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

To run this I use:

```
gunicorn run:app -w 4 -t 10  --preload
```

When calling remove_job for an already created job, the job is removed successfully. But when creating again the job by using `/schedule`, the job seems to be added but never executed by the scheduler.
In addition, following this procedure the program hangs upon start and I have to delete the jobstore to start again.

On the other hand at any point pausing the scheduler, the scheduler doesn't pause.

Do I miss something in the implementation ? or `gunicorn` ? or generally apscheduler?

Thanks

Comment: Log the scheduler and see the wakeup time in the log, I hope you will understand.

Comment: Have already done, seems fine only when the scheduler doesn't hang at startup otherwise it shows nothing at boot time!